# How to create and apply CSS to javascript Alert

Tags: javascript, css, alert

Please tell me, how to apply CSS on javascript Alert.
Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot. `alert()` simply shows a native message box, so it'll look however the OS makes it look.

In general, you shouldn't be using alert boxes because they are annoying and they block the entire browser.* You could always create a fake alert box with JavaScript that achieves the same effect. You could then style it however you want with normal CSS. If you use jQuery, there's [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) ([demos](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/)).

<sup>* Modern browsers tend to only block the window that spawned the alert, but they're still annoying and you still shouldn't use them. :)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible, or else people will use it to phish.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to check jConfirm (jQuery plugin)

http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that. I would suggest you either let it be, or use a modal window. You can also try using modal/dialog plugins e.g. http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sweet alert library of js

[official website](https://sweetalert.js.org/)

[github](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2)

You can also customize the alerts with simple CSS.