# Alert jQuery + CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need help with my jQuery.
I want to make a button that when you press, an alert pops up.
And my question is: can I link a css definition to the alert, so I can design the alerts inside?
Thank You!

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create and apply CSS to javascript Alert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565035/how-to-create-and-apply-css-to-javascript-alert)

Comment: some web searching will provide you with numerous options. Come back if you have implementation problems

Comment: you can not style the browser alert message but you can create your own and style it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**jQuery Dialog**](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Here is the [**API Documentation**](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Hope it'll helps!